# How to Display LineSeries Chart with Point in telerik in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik, telerik-charting

Please help me for display Point in LineSeries in Telerik chart.

Like this...

[image]

in this chart :

```
<telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerikChart:CategoricalAxis  ShowLabels="True" MajorTickBackgroundColor="#A9A9A9" />
</telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
<telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
    <telerikChart:NumericalAxis  Minimum="0" Maximum="500" LineColor="#A9A9A9" MajorTickBackgroundColor="#A9A9A9" />
</telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Wondering the same thing. I assume I will have to make a custom renderer for it.